# TreeMap отсортированный по ключу

Tags: java, алгоритм, сортировка, структуры-данных

Необходим мониторинг количества ip адресов, с которых приходит наибольшее количество пакетов и выводить на экран топ 10 адресов с наибольшим количеством пакетов. Когда приходит пакет я должен записать информацию о нем в структуру данных и обновить монитор.

Есть ли такая структура данных для хранения ключ-значение отсортированная по **значению**, типо `ValueTreeMap<Adress,Integer>`. Постоянно сортировать `Map` не подходит.

**UPDATED**:
Возможно есть структура данных для хранения топ N результатов из большой выборки и при этом вся выборка постоянно обновляется.

Comment: Если у вас будет структура сортируемая по значению элементов и одно из значение изменится, она потеряет сортировку и должна будет её повторить. Отсюда вопрос, чем не подходит сортировать `Map`?

Comment: Количество пакетов приходящих в секунду большое, сортировать весь список после каждого пакета однозначно не подходит.

Comment: Тогда вам никакая коллекция не подойдёт, которая опирается на сортировку. Например, TreeSet будет пересортировываться при каждом добавлении элемента.

Comment: Разве? можно ссылку. Добавление элемента и взятие элемента в сбалансированном дереве O(logN) (TreeSet TreeMap) как мне кажется, в то время как сортировка однозначно дольше. И как я понимаю "перерисовка" в древовидных структурах будет не так часто.

Comment: Кстати хорошая тема. Можно замутить свою реализацию Map с триггером на добавление элемента/инкремент существующего, который банальным пузырьком будет поднимать элемент наверх

Comment: @rjhdby и каждое такое добавление смещает мап. тогда получается каждый раз придется создавать новый мап, добавить до, наш элемент, добавить следующие.  не многовато операций будет? повлияет на производительность

Comment: @SeniorPomidor смотря как реализовать

Comment: Пожалуй займусь, ради саморазвития. Завтра отпишусь, что получилось :)

Comment: Почему не посмотреть в сторону PriorityQueue?

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець не самый лучший вариант. Много допиливать напильником и это все-же очередь - несколько не тот тип коллекции, какой нужен

Answer (score 3):

В первом приближении такая вот штука получилась.

Вроде как

```
get     add      contains   remove    increment    decrement
O(1)    O(2n)    O(1)       O(n)      O(4n)        O(4n)
```

Класс WeightedList ([github](https://github.com/rjhdby/WeightedList))

```
import java.util.*;

public class WeightedList<T> implements List<T> {
    private List<T>         elements = new ArrayList<>();
    private Map<T, Integer> values   = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return elements.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return elements.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return values.containsKey(o);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return elements.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        return elements.toArray();
    }

    @Override
    public <T1> T1[] toArray(T1[] a) {
        return elements.toArray(a);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T t) {
        return add(t, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, T element) {
        add(element, 0);
    }

    public boolean add(T t, Integer weight) {
        if (values.containsKey(t)) {
            return false;
        }
        values.put(t, weight);
        if (elements.size() == 0) {
            elements.add(t);
            return true;
        }
        Integer i = elements.size() - 1;
        while (i >= 0 && getWeight(i) <= weight) i--;
        elements.add(i + 1, t);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean increment(T t) {
        return increment(t, 1);
    }

    public boolean decrement(T t) {
        return decrement(t, 1);
    }

    private boolean increment(T t, Integer amount) {
        if (!values.containsKey(t)) {
            return false;
        }
        Integer weight = values.get(t) + amount;
        if (elements.indexOf(t) == 0) {
            values.put(t, weight);
            return true;
        }
        Integer index = elements.indexOf(t);
        Integer i     = index - 1;
        while (i >= 0 && values.get(elements.get(i)) < weight) i--;
        elements.remove((int) index);
        elements.add(i + 1, t);
        values.put(t, weight);
        return true;
    }

    private boolean decrement(T t, Integer amount) {
        if (!elements.contains(t)) {
            return false;
        }
        Integer weight = values.get(t) - amount;
        if (elements.indexOf(t) == elements.size() - 1) {
            values.put(t, weight);
            return true;
        }
        Integer index = elements.indexOf(t);
        Integer i     = index + 1;
        Integer last  = elements.size();
        while (i < last && values.get(elements.get(i)) > weight) i++;
        elements.add(i, t);
        elements.remove((int) index);
        values.put(t, weight);
        return true;
    }

    public Integer getWeight(T t) {
        return values.get(t);
    }

    public Integer getWeight(int index) {
        return getWeight(elements.get(index));
    }

    public boolean setWeight(T t, Integer weight) {
        if (!elements.contains(t)) return false;
        Integer current = values.get(t);
        if (current < weight) {
            return increment(t, weight - current);
        } else {
            return decrement(t, current - weight);
        }
    }

    public boolean setWeight(int index, Integer weight) {
        return setWeight(elements.get(index), weight);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        values.remove(o);
        return elements.remove(o);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return elements.containsAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> c) {
        for (T element : c) {
            add(element, 0);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends T> c) {
        return addAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        for (Object element : c) {
            remove(element);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        for (T element : elements) {
            if (!c.contains(element)) {
                remove(element);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        elements.clear();
        values.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        return elements.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public T set(int index, T element) {
        T old = elements.get(index);
        elements.remove(index);
        add(element);
        return old;
    }


    @Override
    public T remove(int index) {
        T old = elements.get(index);
        elements.remove(index);
        values.remove(old);
        return old;
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        return elements.indexOf(o);
    }

    @Override
    public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
        return elements.lastIndexOf(o);
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<T> listIterator() {
        return elements.listIterator();
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<T> listIterator(int index) {
        return elements.listIterator(index);
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        return elements.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: add(element, 0); тут думаю надо передать index

Comment: @SeniorPomidor зачем? Логика работы add такова, что вставка начинается с самого низа. Соответственно элемент с весом 0 с очень большой долей вероятности просто добавится в самый конец и прохода по массиву вообще не будет

Comment: есть метод add(T t) {
        return add(t, 0);
который добавляет в конец. а метод add(int index, T element) делает тоже самое. внутри этого метода передается 0 вместо index, или я не так все понял?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor а это грязный хак. Интерфейс `List` требует наличие метода `add(int index, T element) `, но для данной реализации (по сути SortedList), этот метод является даже не бесполезным, а вредным.

Comment: спасибо! теперь понял